# How to display the distance and time travelled between two points using spinners?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to create an app by selecting town-a from one spinner and then town-b from the other spinner.  I then want to display the distance between those towns as well as the time it would take to get there from the selected towns.

I have found something like this:

```
var dist = [
['Town B', [], []],
['Town C', [67], ['1h00m']],
['Town D', [282,251], ['11h10m','10h00m']],
['Town E', [243,210,41], ['9h45m','8h25m','1h40m']],
```

Now this is obviously for HTML dropdown boxes and then calculates from the above file (dist.js)

Now I would like to know how to convert that to using two spinners.   I think I have the basic idea but not sure how to implement.   What I am thinking is when spinner 1 is selected and then spinner 2 then it needs to say that spinner 1 = spinner 2 and the distance is 67km and time to get the is 1h00m.

I don't have code for this cause I haven't tried it yet because I am not sure where to start.   So am hoping someone would help me?

**EDIT**

This is what I have sofar:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

private Spinner startloc;
private Spinner enddes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startloc = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_start = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.start_location,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter_start.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    startloc.setAdapter(adapter_start);
    startloc.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    enddes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter_end = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.end_location,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter_end.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    enddes.setAdapter(adapter_end);
    enddes.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {


}


@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

And this:

```
<string-array name="start_location">
    <item>Town a</item>
    <item>Town b</item>
    <item>Town c</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="end_location">
    <item>Town a</item>
    <item>Town b</item>
    <item>Town c</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="distance">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>67</item>
    <item>282</item>
    <item>251</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="time">
    <item>0m</item>
    <item>2h40m</item>
    <item>11h10m</item>
    <item>10h00m</item>
```

So basically this means:  Town a to Town a is 0 and time is 0,  then Town a to Town b is 67km and time is 2h40m,  Town a to town c is 282km 11h10m and finally Town b to town c 251km and time is 10h00m.  (and needs to obviously work in reverse of list order as well)

Now how do I do this?

Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be hung up on how the data that populates a spinner works in Android.

A Spinner in Android uses an Adapter to fill the Spinner with backing data. The data could be a collection of custom objects, Strings, Integers, etc... The Spinner can also register a listener so that when an item is selected from the Spinner a callback is made that indicates which item was selected.

A very simple implementation would be to use arrays of Strings populate the Spinners. When a selection is made for Spinner1, you'd store that value somewhere. When a selection is made for Spinner2 you'd store that value and check to see that a selection had been made for Spinner1. If a selection had been made for each spinner, then you'd be able to look up the distance / time for each selection. A very simple way to do this would be to use if-else statements:

```
if (spinnerOne.equals("Denver")) {
    if (spinnerTwo.equals("New York") {
        //Print out that distance equals 1280 miles
    } else if (spinnerTwo.equals("San Fransisco") {
        //Etc...
    }
} else if (spinnerOne.equals("New York") {
    //Etc...
}
```

The implementation I describe above is a super simple way of doing it and would work but is mainly just for illustration. There are probably better ways of structuring the data.

Comment: Thank you so much!  will start off with that and build up from there.  :-)

Comment: You'll need to be more clear about what specifically you don't understand how to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry,  What I am trying to accomplish is when the user selects Town a and then selects Town b it should then display the distance which is then 67km and time is 2h40m. (in two textviews) The problem is I don't know how to code that.  I can post the `dist.js file` and html code if that might help :-)

Comment: I tried to post that code but it doesn't seem to let me?

Comment: I have posted a screen shot.